# SVN authz file location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am not able to locate the SVN authz file location.

I am trying to access this file to fix the SVN show logs issue. I get the error to go for offline when i pull show logs.

Comment: The authz file is in the `conf` folder of the repository. Plus, what is the *specific* error message?

Comment: There has been a problem contacting the server Do you want to see the cached data instead?. Along with this it gives couple of options to go offline. Everything works for me except show logs

Comment: I can't find conf folder in the tortise svn installation path and also in my local repo.

Comment: The location depends upon how you're serving your repository. If you're using Apache, it's specified in httpd.conf. If you're using svnserve, it's specified in svnserve.conf. If you have no server configured, it doesn't exist. **It is not necessarily in the repository itself** as this is a new feature in 1.8.

Comment: I am using svn server and i already searched my entire drive for svnserve.conf and could not find it. All i see in my installation directory is 3 folders bin,Diff-scritps,Languages and no conf file in these folders

Comment: @user1427180 you need to look where your *repository* is, not your TortoiseSVN installation. If you set up the repository on *your machine*, then that is where it would be. Otherwise, it would be on a *server* somewhere in your network.